# Split servervariables user_logon

Tags: c#, asp.net

Need to split servervariables user_logon and remove the domain\ part.

Currently it returns as domain\542458

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var numbers = user_logon.Split("\\")[1];
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var user = user_logon.Split("\")[1];
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.split.aspx

Comment: string strLogonUser = Request.ServerVariables["LOGON_USER"].ToString(); var user = strLogonUser.Split("\")[1]; Getting error